# How can I get a resultant scale transform from multiple different scale transforms?

Tags: c#, wpf

I have an itemscontrol with zoom and pan capabilities and I want the user to be able to save a certain view and pan state. I then want the user to be able to click a button and the itemscontrol will be scaled and transformed until it is in the same position the user had it when they clicked save. The pans are easy enough to sort out but I'm having a problem dealing with the scale. If I have multiple scalings I have to do in order to get the itemscontrol in it's previous position, how can I combine them into one resultant scale?

For example, if I have these two scales and they occur on a control in that order, how could I combined them into just one scale so the control ends up in the same position?

```
   Matrix matrix1 = new();
   matrix1.ScaleAt(0.5, 0.5, 100, 0);

   Matrix matrix2 = new();
   matrix2.ScaleAt(0.5, 0.5, 0, 0);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To combine multiple scaling operations into a single matrix transformation, you can use the Matrix.Multiply method.

````
Matrix combinedMatrix = Matrix.Multiply(matrix1, matrix2);
itemsControl.RenderTransform = new MatrixTransform(combinedMatrix); ```
I hope it works
````